# Make grid row take up 100% of leftover space but scroll if more space is needed

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Need to make grid item take up 100% of leftover space but scroll if it needs more space than that.

Below is an example from the scenario. The main part which I can't work out is the CSS line labelled: '/*  DOESN'T WORK */' where I try to set overflow-y to scroll.

Requirements:

- Cart should take up 100% of its container.
- Cart should position the checkout button at the bottom, no matter how many cart items there are.
- Cart items should fill up available space then overflow and scroll once space is filled.

```js
const item = `
  <div class="cart__item">
    T-Shirt
  </div>
`;

const cartItems = document.getElementById("cart__items");

const renderItems = (n) => {
  if (n < 1) {
    cartItems.innerHTML = "cart emtpy";
    return;
  } 
  cartItems.innerHTML = item.repeat(n);
}

let numItems = 1;

const incItems = document.getElementById("inc_items");

incItems.addEventListener("click", () => {
  numItems++;
  renderItems(numItems);
});

const decItems = document.getElementById("dec_items");

decItems.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (numItems > 0) { numItems--; }
  renderItems(numItems);
});

renderItems(numItems);
```

```css
.container {
  height: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  background: pink;
}

.cart {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr max-content;
}

.cart__item {
  outline: 2px solid red;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}

.cart__items {
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
/*   overflow-y: scroll; */ /*  DOESN'T WORK */
  outline: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button id="inc_items">Inc Item</button>
<button id="dec_items">Dec Item</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="cart">
    <div id="cart__items" class="cart__items"></div>
    <div class="cart__checkout">
      <button>Checkout</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: overflow:auto ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dozjapnf/

Answer (score -1):

Adding `width` and `height` to `100%` in `.cart` do the job:

```css
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

and you need to un-comment your line in `.cart__items`:

```css
overflow-y: scroll;
```

or you can let the browser decide with:

```css
overflow: auto;
```

Check snippet below :

```css
.container {
  height: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  background: pink;
}

.cart {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr max-content;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cart__item {
  outline: 2px solid red;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}

.cart__items {
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  /* or overflow-y: scroll; */
  outline: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button id="inc_items">Inc Item</button>
<button id="dec_items">Dec Item</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="cart"> 
    <div id="cart__items" class="cart__items">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dignissim felis non felis mollis, ac pellentesque libero tincidunt. Quisque commodo felis vitae mi facilisis placerat eu a dui. Vestibulum ultrices accumsan elit a sollicitudin. Mauris porta, leo sit amet condimentum tincidunt, velit nunc ultricies nibh, imperdiet elementum felis sem sit amet ex. Proin molestie urna sed vulputate ornare. Sed vel pulvinar sem, sit amet condimentum ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dignissim felis non felis mollis, ac pellentesque libero tincidunt. Quisque commodo felis vitae mi facilisis placerat eu a dui. Vestibulum ultrices accumsan elit a sollicitudin. Mauris porta, leo sit amet condimentum tincidunt, velit nunc ultricies nibh, imperdiet elementum felis sem sit amet ex. Proin molestie urna sed vulputate ornare. Sed vel pulvinar sem, sit amet condimentum ante. </div>
    <div class="cart__checkout">
      <button>Checkout</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```